# Logging between modules in Python

Tags: python, logging

I am learning logging with the standard Python library documentation and it seems I am missing something trivial. I want to have logging in multiple modules but configure each instance only in the main file. I think that what I am doing wrong is that basicConfig only works for the functions that control the root logger, but I am confused.

Could you point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

```
# main.py
import logging
import module_log

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARNING)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def test1():
    logger.warning("This one is not showing in log but that is what I expect")
    module_log.test2()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test1()


# module.py
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def test2():
    logger.warning("This one shouldn't be showing in log but it is")
```

**EDIT 1:** Updated the code to better illustrate the problem.

**EDIT 2:** I think I found the source of the problem, even thought I don't fully understand why. I was not executing the main.py directly, I was calling it from within the Maya(3d software) interpreter (but the same happens with the Python interpreter) If you run:

```
>>> import main_log
>>> main_log.test1()
```

It works! But then I changed main_log.py to change the debug level. I am used to run "reload()" when updating modules but with this specific module it seems not to be working so it kept showing the same results and that why I was getting always the same results no matter what the debug level was.

```
>>> reload(main_log)
>>> main_log.test1()
```

Until this point, my only workaround is shutting down Maya completely and re-opening it (guess the same happens within the python interpreter). I will appreciate any further help!

Comment: With two files `main.py` and `module.py` as shown, I cannot reproduce the behavior you describe; the warning from each is only displayed if `logging.basicConfig` sets the logging level to `logging.WARNING` or lower.

Comment: @chepner you are right, the problem wasn't the code. It was interpreter I was using. Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 3):

In one sense, yes, `basicConfig` only configures the root logger. However, any logger you get from `logging.getLogger` will inherit its configuration from the root logger.

If you want specialized behavior for the loggers in your module, either configure it in your module using methods such as `Logger.addHandler` and `Logger.setLevel`, or rely on the main application to use `logging.config.fileConfig` so that configuration for *all* loggers can be set via a configuration file. However, in general your module should be concerned with *what* gets logged, and leave it up to whatever uses the module to determine *where*, if anywhere, the logged messages are sent.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your issue may be because the `import module` call in `main.py` ends up running `logging.getLogger()` in your `module.py` before your `logging.basicConfig()` call, which gets a logger that is configured with the default level of WARNING.

Try avoiding calling `getLogger()` in the module scope.

Note that your `getLogger(__name__)` calls are returning different logger objects between the different modules, because `__name__` is the name of the individual module it's called in.

If you're not writing a multi-threaded program, it may be simpler to just call `logging.basicConfig()` in your `__main__` function, and have all the modules do logging with `logging.warning()`, `logging.error()`, etc.  Then you can pass in a formatter to your `logging.basicConfig()` call to show the filename, line number, etc in the log to record what line of code emitted the log.

Comment: I was originally evaluating what you said in the last paragraph. However, I wouldn't be able to know from what module the log is coming from right? Or is there a workaround for the root logger to update the name it logs depending on the module that is currently running?

Comment: LogRecord object can recognize these special attributes in your format string: https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes, so you can use the module or filename to record where the log came from.